# How to convert API date to string in Kotlin within my recyclerview adapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, simpledateformat

I need to convert API date from this (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) format to (oct 18) like this

```
 @Throws(ParseException::class)
    private fun getFormate(date: String): String? {
        val d: Date = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(date)
        //Log.d("Date", String.valueOf(d));
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
        cal.time = d
        return SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd").format(cal.time)
    }

inside of onBindViewHolder

val thisModelResponse: ExpiryData = expiryList.get(position)
        holder.expiryDate1.text = getFormate(thisModelResponse.getCreatedDate())
        holder.expiryDate1.text = (expiryItem.expiryDate)
```

But i'm getting error unresolved refference in getCreatedDate()

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends like `Calendar`. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Please show us the code where you think you have declared and implemented `getCreatedDate()`. Best [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also `getCreatedDate()` should probably return an `Instant` or another object defining a point in time. Not a `String`. Your methods that give you numbers and Boolean values don’t return strings either, do they?

Answer (score 0):

To convert date from string, returning a new parsed date you must do:

```
val inputDate = "2018-10-18 11:00:00"
val inputDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val outputDate = inputDateFormat.parse(inputDate)
val outputDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd")
val result : String = outputDateFormat.format(outputDate)
```

**result** will be "Oct 18"